# Decode JWT token on nginx server and log it

Tags: nginx, jwt

We are using nginx server for reverse proxying few micro-services. Every request has `Authorization` header containing JWT token. Now, what we need to do is extract user details from JWT token and log it on nginx server. Is there anyway to decode and log JWT? I looked into few lua scripts for authenticating request using JWT but that is not what we need. Also, we are trying to avoid using installing Lua on nginx server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** We are fine with Lua based solution as well.

Comment: Was JWT created using Lua or which language ?

Comment: @Fawaz JWT was created using node.js on one of the servers proxied by nginx. Nginx receives this token in request headers. I need to decode it and log user details on nginx server.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.nginx.com/blog/authenticating-api-clients-jwt-nginx-plus/

Comment: It uses nginx plus.

Comment: see https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc#sample-configuration-for-oauth-20-jwt-token-validation, you can add logging of the decoded "res" returned from bearer_jwt_verify yourself

Answer (score 1):

Relating to your problem and following the comments you could use the official Nginx Plus module to approach in the best way the task:

[Authenticating API Clients with JWT and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/authenticating-api-clients-jwt-nginx-plus/)

But this obviously cost money and in case you want something open-source you should check this project:

[TeslaGov /ngx-http-auth-jwt-module](https://github.com/TeslaGov/ngx-http-auth-jwt-module)

The above module, is working now a days, it's not easy as use the Nginx plus module but it's opensource.

To finish, relating to your Edition, here is a Lua solution.

[ubergarm / openresty-nginx-jwt](https://github.com/ubergarm/openresty-nginx-jwt)

I am not very into Lua and the project seems to be outdated due it doesn't receive an update since 2018, I share you the link in case you can found something useful from it.

I hope this helps to solve your problem, regards.